# Access microphone on mac osx by application created in java and packed into .dmg

Tags: java, macos, macos-catalina, privacy

I am making a java aplication for macOs. It use microphone for voice recording.

When I run my aplication from command line using "java -jar ..." it ask me for microphone access and it is possible to record something.

When I create a dmg package and run it after installation it never ask for microphone permission and it does not record.
I am using using javapackager to create a package.

I have added following entries into Info.plist

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This application needs access to your Microphone</string>
```

My package includes java runtime and both Info.plist are updated

```
/Applications/<name>.app/Contents/Info.plist

/Applications/<name>.app/Contents/PlugIns/Java.runtime/Contents/Info.plist
```

Have I missed something? What shoult I add to trigger microphone permission alert?

Should I notarize application first?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I'm very stuck on this problem